# Internal SSD is picked up as Windows To Go workspace

Tags: windows, usb, ssd, windows-to-go

I just upgraded to a 1TB M.2 SSD in my ASUS TUF Gaming A15 laptop. To do this, I used a 2TB external SSD and Clonezilla. However, after the upgrade, Windows will now display this message on boot:

> ### Keep the USB drive plugged in.
>
> Only remove it after your PC has shut down completely. Otherwise, your Windows To Go workspace might crash and you could lose data.

This message implies that Windows thinks my internal SSD is a Windows To Go drive, which it is not. This occurs even with no USB devices attached (including the external SSD used to upgrade). How do I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: We need more information such as screenshot from disk manager

Comment: This is due to an erroneous registry key. This is an easy problem to solve.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control" and change the value "PortableOperatingSystem” from 1 to 0